# Visual Studio: Manage debugging command line arguments for the app

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, command-line-arguments

Is there any simple way to manage command line arguments for C++ project (I suppose the same for C#) in Visual Studio like it works in Visual Studio Code where you have dropdown with different run presets? I'm developing CLI and need to change arguments pretty often. Now I have to copy paste them from txt file. I guess it's not the easiest way to handle this :)

UPD: Just to clarify I'm speaking about Console application project properties -> Debugging -> Command Arguments block.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Visual Studio command line arguments". Do you refer to the C++ **compiler** cmd line args in the project settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command for [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) to set command line arguments for a selected C++ startup project and start debugging:

(Language: C#, References: Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine)

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine;

public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        Project startupProject = DTE.Solution.Item(((DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild as SolutionBuild2).StartupProjects as object[])[0]);
        VCProject vcproj = startupProject.Object as VCProject;
        VCConfiguration vcconfig = vcproj.ActiveConfiguration;
        VCDebugSettings vcdebug = vcconfig.DebugSettings as VCDebugSettings;
        vcdebug.CommandArguments = "my_arguments_1";
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.Start");
    }
}
```

Having several such commands with different arguments, you can quickly select and run them from the VCmd menu.

Comment: That looks cool! Thanks for the advice. Slightly strange editor window in the plugin without any syntax highlighting but it does the trick :)

Comment: Need to mention that that plugin costs really a lot: $50 just for debug parameters manager is a lot. Free edition has limitation in 10 commands which makes it useless.