# Setting debugging parameters on multiple projects in VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

In Visual Studio 2019, it appears no longer possible to set the command, command arguments and working directory of multiple projects simultaneously. As soon as multiple projects are selected, the Debugging category disappears:

Single project selected:

[image]

Multiple (executable) projects selected:

[image]

(Notice that the Debugging category in the left pane is gone.)

**Is there a less tedious way than manually setting those on all individual (executable) projects?**

Comment: There is an API to set these properties programmatically. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938771/visual-studio-manage-debugging-command-line-arguments-for-the-app for an example how to set it for the first startup project.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned, It is not possible to set commands, command parameters and working directories for multiple projects at the same time in the property page.

I suggest you could try to use [customize your build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019).

> you can add a new property to every project in one step by defining it
>   in a single file called Directory.Build.props in the root folder that
>   contains your source. When MSBuild runs, Microsoft.Common.props
>   searches your directory structure for the Directory.Build.props file
>   (and Microsoft.Common.targets looks for Directory.Build.targets). If
>   it finds one, it imports the property. Directory.Build.props is a
>   user-defined file that provides customizations to projects under a
>   directory.

For more details I suggest you could refer to the link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019